# SQL / SQLAlchemy Count on different dates

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, sum

> The same question on how to do it in SQL, with views or a stored procedure?

I have a sales table simplified by 4 columns namely id, product_id, sale_date and quantity. I would like to build a request returning :
  1. for each product_id the total sales by date in one row
  2. on the same row for each id the total sales on 7, 15, 30 days

For now, I use multiple WITH-views, one for each columns :

```
days7=session.query(Sales.product_id,func.sum(Sales.quantity).label('count')).\
              filter(Sales.sale_date > now() - timedelta(days=7)).\
               group_by(Sales.product_id).cte('days7')
...
req=session.query(Sales.product_id,days7.c.count.label('days7'),\
                                 days15.c.count.label('days15'),\
                                 days30.c.count.label('days30')).\
            outerjoin(days7,days7.c.product_id==Sales.product_id).\
            outerjoin(days15,days15.c.product_id==Sales.product_id).\
            outerjoin(days30,days30.c.product_id==Sales.product_id).\
            all()
```

It works pretty well but I not sure if this is the best way of doing it. Moreover if I want to add the count for each date of the 30 (or 360) previous days, it becomes crazy. The idea could have been to use a simple for loop :

```
viewSumByDay=[]
for day in range(180):
  date=now()-timedelta(days=day)
  viewSumByDay.append(session.query(...).cte(str(date.date())))
```

which is ok to create the view. And although for the left join it should also be ok with a `req=req.outerjoin(viewSumByDay[day],...)`, I'm now stuck on how to use the loop to add the columns into the main query.

Do you see another nice solution?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Which one of dbms you are using?

Comment: postgresql. But it appears it is far more efficient to compute the sum in python after querying for the simple records... Is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry, a simple `req=req.add_column(...)` is described in the documentation.

However if there is a prettier way, I would like to know it.